# Is it possible to show data from two different room database tables into single viewpager

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager, android-room, kotlin-flow

I have two fragments in my app one is QuotesFragment and Another is FavouritesFragments both of which get their data from room database from two differnt tables and display it into a recycleview and on item click go to another fragment namely QuoteDetailFragment which displays the data in view pager.

Everything works fine  if i do it seperately but how can i show data from both sources into a single viewpager based on the fragment user is comming from  or do i need to create seperate viewpagers for both the sources .
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code :

Dao

```
   @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM quotes INNER JOIN categories ON quotes.category_id = categories.id " +
            "WHERE categories.id = :categoryId")
    fun getQuotesByCategory(categoryId: Int): Flow<List<QuotesByCategory>>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM favourites ORDER BY date DESC")
    fun getAllFavourites(): Flow<List<Favourite>>
```

QuoteDetailFragment.kt

```
  val incomingFragment = arguments?.getString(Constants.STRING_EXTRA_INCOMING_FRAGMENT)

        val db = AppDatabase.getDatabase(requireContext()).quoteDao()
        viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager)

        if (incomingFragment != null && incomingFragment.contains(Constants.FRAGMENT_QUOTE)){
            lifecycle.coroutineScope.launch {
                db.getQuotesByCategory(categoryId).collect {
                    adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(requireContext(), quoteList = it)
                    viewPager.adapter = adapter
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(position, false)
                }

            }
        }

        if (incomingFragment != null && incomingFragment.contains(Constants.FRAGMENT_FAVOURITE)){
            lifecycle.coroutineScope.launch {
                db.getAllFavourites().collect {
                    adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(requireContext(), quoteList = it )
                    viewPager.adapter = adapter
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(position, false)
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

ViewPagerAdapter.kt

```
class ViewPagerAdapter (private val context: Context,
                        private val quoteList: List<QuotesByCategory>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewPagerAdapter.ViewHolder>() {


    inner class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val tvQuotes: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.vp_quotes)
        val favouriteBtn: ImageButton = view.findViewById(R.id.vp_fav)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.quote_detail_viewpager, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        val currentQuote = quoteList[position].quotes[position]
        val id = currentQuote.id
        val quote = currentQuote.quote
        val catName = quoteList[position].category.categoryName

        holder.tvQuotes.text = quote

        val favouritesDao = AppDatabase.getDatabase(context).quoteDao()

        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            if (favouritesDao.isFavourite(currentQuote.id)) {
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    holder.favouriteBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite)
                }
            }
        }

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return quoteList.size
    }
}
```

The following line gives me error

Type mismatch.
Required:List
Found: List

```
 db.getAllFavourites().collect {
             adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(requireContext(), quoteList = it )   // This line gives me error
              viewPager.adapter = adapter
               viewPager.setCurrentItem(position, false)
            }
```

Comment: getAllFavourites() returns Flow<List<QuotesByCategory>>. Your ViewPagerAdapter is expecting List<Favourite> but you are providing List<QuotesByCategory>.

Comment: But that does not answer ops question